# Changing the async wait time in Polymer

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, polymer

Using Polymer's async function is there a way to change the remaining wait time after it's been called? To contextualise usage, a popup modal is currently setup to disappear after 3 seconds once its opened using async, but it needs to extend wait time if the user hovers over it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Polymer has no API to change the timeout of an active timer, but you could stop the timer with [`cancelAsync()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-cancelAsync) and restart it with another call to [`async()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-async).

```
// initially...
this._timer = this.async(() => ..., 5000);

// on mouse-hover...
this.cancelAsync(this._timer);
this._timer = this.async(() => ..., 2000);
```